# Google Cloud Storage Caching js file

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I have a js file that I store in Google Cloud Storage which is being served quite a lot. It's starting to increase the cost of my cloud bill ("Networking Traffic Egress GAE/Firebase Storage" is up to the roof). Would it help add anything in the Cache part? What is the best way to decrease the cost of serving this JS? (Yes, I will also work on decreasing the actual size which is currently 1.8mb).

[image: JS File]

[image: current metadata]

Comment: If you found the answer helpful please remember to mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1):

You can change the value of `Cache-Control` to enable cache.

See here https://www.imperva.com/learn/performance/cache-control/